# One to One Relationship in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

Collection blog:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId( "47cc67093475061e3d95369d" )
    title:
    body:
    author:
}
```

I wanna know the following two examples which is better as the blog.replies collection.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId( "47cc67093475061e3d95369d" )
    replies: [
    ]
}


{
    _id: ObjectId( "56a463497875061e5d443607" )
    blog_id: ObjectId( "47cc67093475061e3d95369d" )
    replies: [
    ]
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use example 2

```
{
    _id: ObjectId( "56a463497875061e5d443607" )
    blog_id: ObjectId( "47cc67093475061e3d95369d" )
    replies: [
    ]
}
```

For show page:

```
db.blog.find({"_id" : ObjectId("47cc67093475061e3d95369d")}); // get blog page
db.replies.find({"blog_id" : ObjectId("47cc67093475061e3d95369d")}); // get blog replies
```

Comment: Why do you say option 2 is better?

Comment: Look at "get blog replies"